# Virtualbox access webservices on guest via a url

Tags: url, networking, virtualbox, names

im running windows 7 as host and ubuntu 11.04 as guest. 
Which would be the best way to access a webserver on a guest from host via a defined url
(and vise versa)
e.g http://myvirtualbox and http://myhost

For now i have configured a network bridge, but the guest is gets a different ip assigned everytime. A simple solution would be to assign a staic ip and configure a name resolution localy on each machine, but maybe there is an other way (internal netwok perhaps?)

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the hosts file on machines to map the hostname to the IP addresses of the machines (and change their IP addresses to static).

Or another more flexible (more hosts, faster integration for new machines) option: you're going to want to set up a DNS service, configure the machines to work with it, then add the IP of the DNS as a name server in your network adapter for the hosts to use.

That will be a more flexible, maintainable and scalable solution.

From the looks of it though, if you want a 10 minute fix, go for the first option.  There are lots of tutorials on it.